# Can neural networks fit a/b?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I try to fit a/b with mlp using Keras,here is my code:

```py
x,y = [],[]
for i in range(100000):
    k = []
    for j in range(2):
        k.append(random.random())
    x.append(k)
    y.append(k[0]/k[1])
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
trainx = x[:80000]
trainy = y[:80000]
valx = x[80000:]
valy = y[80000:]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu',input_shape=(len(trainx[0]),)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='tanh'))
opt = optimizers.RMSprop()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt, metrics=["mae"])
model.fit(trainx,trainy,batch_size=100,epochs=100,verbose=1,validation_data=(valx,valy))
```

and output is :

```py
80000/80000 [==============================] - 6s 78us/step - loss:25299.1590 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5678 - val_loss: 10557.5025 -val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5637
80000/80000 [==============================] - 4s 47us/step - loss: 25299.1220 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5502 - val_loss: 10557.5016 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5513
80000/80000 [==============================] - 4s 48us/step - loss: 25299.1225 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5475 - val_loss: 10557.5015 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5509
80000/80000 [==============================] - 4s 49us/step - loss: 25299.1219 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5462 - val_loss: 10557.5016 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5556
80000/80000 [==============================] - 4s 47us/step - loss: 25299.1223 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5456 - val_loss: 10557.5016 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5544
80000/80000 [==============================] - 4s 48us/step - loss: 25299.1221 - mean_absolute_error: 5.5451 - val_loss: 10557.5015 - val_mean_absolute_error: 4.5508
```

I dont know what's wrong with my code. I also tried `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` to generate more features, but nothing changed.

Comment: Usually your input shape for x should be the number of features, in this case 2 -- not the number of samples. Also, standardize your data to have mean 0 and variance 1 based on the training data.

Comment: Of course, your error will be high, because you are using `tanh` activation, which restricts your output to the unreasonable range of `(-1,1)`.

Comment: @user36624   You're right,tanh will restrict range. But mse is still too high after deleting activation. Is it difficult for nn to learn this problem? Or something wrong with my code or data?